# New instance of MVVM Window breaks the bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

It’s my first week into WPF from Windows Forms and I’m already forced to go to MVVM pattern because almost every tutorial or Stack Overflow answer I stumble upon has this kind of pattern in mind.

Because I have already put a lot of work in my existing project, I am testing MVVM pattern on a single window, in order to see its potential.

Having this cleared, I have Window1, UserControl1 and UserControl2 views, each one having a corresponding `ViewModel`.

The Window1 is used to navigate between UserControl1 and UserControl2 and each of the user controls has a button for switching to the other user control.

The navigation is based on the tutorial that Rachel Lim provided (https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/. Everything seems to work as intended at the first instance of Window1.

However, if I close Window1 instance and open another one, the buttons in the user controls no longer change the ControlControl that is placed in Window1.

Also, if keep the first Window1 open, create another Window1 instance and click the button that would set UserControl2 as content control in the second Window1 instance, it is not that instance that changes its content control but the first one.

My conclusion is that, somehow, all the bindings are made with the first instance that it is launched but I cannot figure out why.

[Here is my project.](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1ec784aa738cc11b5821e2e237fddbe520200404190756/aea990)

Some relevant part of XAML and CS codes:

**Method for launching Window1, that is located in another Window:**

```
Window1 window = new Window1();
Window1ViewModel context = new Window1ViewModel();
window.DataContext = context;
window.Show();
```

**XAML of Window1:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl1ViewModel}">
        <local:UserControl1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl2ViewModel}">
        <local:UserControl2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

**Window1ViewModel class**

```
class Window1ViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
        private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

        public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPageViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentPageViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
            }
        }

        private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
        }

        private void OnGoTo1(object obj)
        {
            ChangeViewModel(PageViewModels[0]);

        }

        private void OnGoTo2(object obj)
        {
            ChangeViewModel(PageViewModels[1]);

        }

        public Window1ViewModel()
        {
            // Add available pages and set page
            PageViewModels.Clear();
            PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl1ViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl2ViewModel());
            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo1", OnGoTo1);
            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo2", OnGoTo2);

        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? I cannot figure why it keeps all the bindings with the first Window instance, even if I am creating a new class.

Comment: Your project URL (https://file.io/CjEATl) is broken. Page Not Found

Comment: @Zaheer I have changed the file hosting service. It was somehow deleted immediately.

Comment: this may be the next level, but: your usercontrols probably shouldn't have viewmodels. Compare a `TextBlock` - it doesn't have a viewmodel. it has a lot of dependencyproperties though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the navigation buttons are not part of the `Window1` control and bind to the `Window1ViewModel`, which is the `DataContext` of `Window1`. If so, you have to reuse the same `Window1ViewModel` instance for every instance of `Window1`.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private Window1ViewModel Window1ViewModel { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.Window1ViewModel = new Window1ViewModel();
  }

  private void ShowWindow1()
  {
    Window1 window = new Window1();
    window.DataContext = this.Window1ViewModel;
    window.Show();
  }
}
```

If creating a new instance of `Window1ViewModel` is a requirement, then you should redesign the view and move the navigation buttons to the `Window1` control.

### Remarks

I'll try to explain why you have to reuse the initial instance of `Window1ViewModel` in your current implementation.

It's a matter of scope and instances or instance references.

Let's take your initial setup as context: we have a first control e.g., a `Button` that binds to the `DataContext` e.g. `Window1ViewModel` of a second control e.g., `Window1`.
The bindings to `Window1ViewModel` initially work, but when you close `Window1` and open a new instance of `Window1`, then those bindings no longer work.

To understand what's really happening, you have to remember, that you are not dealing with classes, but with *instances* of classes. You can have multiple instances of the same class.

Generally, the binding information (source object and target object of the data binding) is stored in an instance of the class `Binding`.

Now, when setting up a XAML binding on a property of the first control (the `Button.Command`) e.g. to bind to a command of a `Window1ViewModel` instance, the framework will create a new instance of `Binding`, where its `Binding.Target` property is set to `Button.Command` (a property on the current instance of `Button`) and the `Binding.Source` property is set to the current (first) *instance* of `Window1ViewModel` (and to the instance's property e.g. `NextPageCommand`).

You show the window like this:

```
private void ShowWindow1()
{
  Window1 window = new Window1();
  window.DataContext = new Window1ViewModel();
  window.Show();
}
```

When you now close `Window1` and leave the scope of the `window` instance variable, you cannot access the first `Window1ViewModel` instance anymore, because the only reference to this instance was stored in the `DataContext` property of `Window1`. But *still*, the binding of the `Button` references the first instance of `Window1ViewModel`.

You then decide to show a new window and instantiate a new (second) instance of `Window1` and assign it a new (second) instance of `Window1ViewModel`. How does the binding now about the new instance of `Window1ViewModel`?
Even when you are reusing the first `Window1` instance and just add a new instance of `Window1ViewModel` to the `Window1.DataContext`, the binding still references the very first (initial) instance of `Window1ViewModel`.

`Binding` doesn't derive from `DependencyObject` and therefore doesn't implement its properties as `DependencyProperty`. This means `Binding.Source` is not a `DependencyProperty` and can't trigger property changes and therefore will not update the reference to point to the second instance of `Window1ViewModel`. That's why reusing the initial instance of `Window1ViewModel` solves the problem (`Binding.Source` still references it).

Alternatively you could've replaced the `Binding` instance when replacing the binging source instance. But this would require to write more complex C# code, without XAML designer help to resolve the current `DataContext`.

### Solution

When taking a look at the logic you are trying to implement, it really doesn't make sense to have a single set of navigation buttons to navigate multiple independent windows.

If you decide to have multiple `Window1` instances running in parallel, then you must let `Window1` handle the navigation by itself.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<window>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="LoadPreviousButton" 
            Command="ShowPreviousCommand}" />
    <Button x:Name="LoadNextButton"
            Command="ShowNextCommand}" />

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Now you can have as much `Window1` instances as you like, where each `Window1` instance can have a dedicated instance of `Window1ViewModel`:

```
// This will now behave as you expected it to
var window = new Window1() { DataContext = new Window1ViewModel() };
window.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!
With the updated code, if I have multiple windows open, using the navigation buttons in one window changes the UserControl in both windows.
I don’t understand why I cannot create a new instance of the ViewModel class with every instance of the Window class and get them to work independently. Could you provide me a link for further research of this subject?
I guess that, for now, I could keep just one Window1ViewModel and reuse that, using only one window at a time.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain why you have to reuse the view model instance (in your current implementation) and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two changes. One is, you have to Unsubscribe Mediator in Window1ViewModel.cs

```
public Window1ViewModel()
{
    Mediator.Unsubscribe("GoTo1", OnGoTo1);
    Mediator.Unsubscribe("GoTo2", OnGoTo2);
    // Add available pages and set page
    PageViewModels.Clear();
    PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl1ViewModel());
    PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl2ViewModel());
    CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

    Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo1", OnGoTo1);
    Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo2", OnGoTo2);
}
```

Second, you have to update Unsubscribe method in Mediator class:

```
public static void Unsubscribe(string token, Action<object> callback)
{
    if (pl_dict.ContainsKey(token)) {
        //pl_dict[token].Remove(callback);
        pl_dict.Remove(token);
    }
}
```

Before, this method was removing callback of token only, but it should actually remove the Subscription entry.

Comment: I have made the changes but I think the Solution to my problem has to do with the answer BionicCode posted